# How to use SIGAR to remotely fetch another machine's system info?

Tags: java, jmx, sigar

I'm working on a project that requires to show the CPU usage as well as other system information of remote machines.
People suggest using SIGAR to achieve this, but I don't know how to use it. The source code didn't quite make sense to me.
Basically, my question is that: how can I register the MBeans provided by SIGAR to the server when host IP and JMX port are provided, and how to fetch the system info from other computer afterward.
Please correct me if I'm wrong with how JMX works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you will have to write some wrapping objects to expose the various SIGAR outputs as JMX mbean attributes.  How you do that that depends highly on what you are using to expose your JMX beans.  I would write one wrapping object for each of the various different types of SIGAR output: memory, disk, ...

I've written a [SimpleJMX library](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) that might help.  I'll use its format to provide an example object that you can use to expose the info via JMX.  You can adapt it to whatever mechanism you are using to publish JMX means.  I'm not familiar with SIGAR enough to know if my sigar code below is correct to get a `ProcMem` instance.

```
@JmxResource(description = "Show SIGAR Info", domainName = "foo")
public class SigarProcMem {

    private ProcMem procMem;

    {
      // sorry, I'm not up on sigar so I'm not sure if this works
      Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
      procMem = sigar.getProcMem(sigar.getPid());
    }

    @JmxAttributeMethod(description = "Resident memory")
    public long residentMemory() {
       return procMem.getResident();
    }

    @JmxAttributeMethod(description = "Get the Total process virtual memory")
    public long totalVirtualMemory() {
       return procMem.getSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: nifty library.  we implemented a similar library where i work.  curious why you smash the parameter info in the JmxOperation annotation instead of having a separate annotation for the parameters?

Comment: @jtahlborn  Heh.  I just hate the complexity of that.  I always have to look up how to do an array of annotation fields or copy another instance.  I don't use it enough to remember.  :-)

Comment: i think you misunderstood me.  i was referring to having a separate annotation which you put on the method parameters (no arrays involved in that).  i think that's much simpler than the arrays of values in the JmxOperation.

Comment: @jtahlborn Oh right.  That's so rarely done that I forget about it.  Not exactly sure.  I guess intermixing paramaters and annotations might harm readability.   I'll add it to the TODO list to investigate.

Comment: Not sure if this is what I actually want. Maybe my problem is just with the process of exposing MBeans.

Comment: Unless SIGAR supports JMX directly, you are going to have to publish the beans yourself @Luka.  How are you using JMX now?

Answer (score 0):

These are the names of the classes that are the Sigar built in MBeans that you can register:

- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarCpu
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarCpuInfo
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarCpuPerc
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarLoadAverage
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarMem
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarProcess
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarRegistry
- org.hyperic.sigar.jmx.SigarSwap

However, it will be quite complicated to deploy these remotely since Sigar depends on a native library which must be in the target JVM's lib-path when the MBeans are loaded. This means, you will need to actively load the library and MBeans on each target host you want to monitor.

You might be able to hack a way of making the target JVMs load this through a remote call, but it is non-trivial and will require you to bypass any security setups in the JVMs since by default, this is something you're not supposed to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of hack the system part to get an easy deployment for Sigjar:

```
private String before;
private Sigar sigar;

/**
 * Constructor - don't forget to call unload later!
 */
public SetlogSigar() throws Exception {
    before = System.getProperty("java.library.path");

    String path = "";

    String add = getJarFolder();

    if (before.contains(";"))
        path = before + ";./;" + add;
    else
        path = before + ":./:" + add;

    setSystemPath(path);

    sigar = new Sigar();

}

/**
 * This is needed to dynamically update the JAVA Path environment in order to load the needed native library
 * Yes -rather an ugly hack...
 */
private String getJarFolder() {
    // get name and path
    String path = SetlogSigar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    String decodedPath = path;
    try {
        decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }    

    File f = new File(decodedPath);
    String absolutePath = f.getParentFile().getParentFile().getParentFile().getParent()+"/lib";

    return absolutePath;
}

/**
 * Unloads the JNI bindings
 */
public void unload() {
    this.sigar.close();
    setSystemPath(before);
}
```

This hack dynamically adds the folder where sigjar.jar is located to the environment variable. Just place all native libs in there and deployment gets less complicated.